# Consultar 2 bases de datos con entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

He estado investigado como consultar 2 tablas que cada una existe en su respectiva base de datos, para esto el campo que buscara la coincidencia es **Numero_Cliente**  en la *Tabla OrdenesPT*, esta es alojada en una base de datos  y en la *Tabla Cliente* es **NumeroCliente** y esta esta alojada en la segunda base de datos que deseo buscar la coincidencia.
Buscando en algunos foros aparecía la información que debía de declarar los 2 contextos para poder hacer uso de ellos, los hice de la siguiente manera:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Actualizacion/BuscarRegistrosReportes")]
public IEnumerable BuscarRegistrosReportes()
{
 var contextBDPT = new ProductoTerminadoContext();
 var contextBDCOT = new CotizadorDBContext();

 var listainfo = from b in contextBDPT.OrdenesPt.AsNoTracking().ToList()
                      join bt in contextBDCOT.Clientes.AsNoTracking().ToList()
                      on b.Numero_Cliente equals bt.NumeroCliente
                      select b;
            return listainfo;
}
```

Pero especificamente donde realizo el **JOIN**, Me marca error *El tipo de una de las expresiones de la cláusula join es incorrecto. No se pudo realizar la inferencia de tipos en la llamada a 'Join'.*

Busque otra solución y fue crear un procedimiento almacenado y lo mande a llamar de la siguiente manera:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/Actualizacion/BuscarRegistrosReportes")]
public IEnumerable BuscarRegistrosReportes()
{
   using (ProductoTerminadoContext bd = new ProductoTerminadoContext())
   {
         var resultado = (from b in bd.OrdenesPt.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE dbo.BuscarDatosConSalidas")
                                 select b).ToList();
                
         return resultado;
   }
}
```

Pero solo me trae los datos definidos en la tabla OrdenesPT, y no se como poder mostrar los que me hacen falta de la base de datos Cotizador, si tienen algún ejemplo o algo que me pueda basar lo agradecería.

Procedimiento almacenado que realice

```
USE [ProductoTerminado]
GO    
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[BuscarDatosConSalidas]
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * from 
ProductoTerminado.dbo.OrdenesPT 
INNER JOIN 
Cotizador.dbo.Clientes ON 
Cotizador.dbo.Clientes.NumeroCliente=ProductoTerminado.dbo.OrdenesPT.Numero_Cliente 
INNER JOIN
ProductoTerminado.dbo.Transportes on 
ProductoTerminado.dbo.OrdenesPT.OT = ProductoTerminado.dbo.Transportes.OT
where ProductoTerminado.dbo.OrdenesPT.Salida ='X' and ProductoTerminado.dbo.OrdenesPT.SalidaEmp = 'X'
END
```

Comment: El procedimiento almacenado puede ser la opción, pero hace falta ver el código que tienes.

Comment: Es una web api, entonces solo tengo lo que describí arriba, agregare el procedimiento en la pregunta

Comment: Tranquilamente podrías ejecutar ambas listas en dos variable diferentes y luego hacer la intersección.

Comment: @fredyfx me podrías proporcionar un ejemplo o donde lo pueda consultar

Comment: Claro, aunque dudo que sea tal cual quieres porque falta información en la pregunta. Te dejo un ejemplo.

Comment: ¿Que información crees que falte?

Comment: Toda la necesaria para que cualquier persona que lea tu pregunta, pueda reproducir el escenario que tienes. Desde cero. Lectura sugerida: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136916/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-enrique-de-jesus-juarez-cruz).

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente ejemplo puede ser de utilidad para hacer un par de llamadas a distintas bases de datos y tener los datos en una variable para cada lista, a partir de ello, encontrar la intersección mediante Linq:

```
string[] Customers_Of_Company_A = {
  "Tina",
  "Amit",
  "Jack",
  "Ritu"
};
string[] Customers_Of_Company_B = {
  "Jack",
  "Sumit",
  "Joe",
  "Alen"
};
var intersectResult = Customers_Of_ Company_A.Intersect(Customers_Of_Company_B);
Console.WriteLine("Common Customers from both the companies are:");
foreach(var names in intersectResult) {
  Console.WriteLine(names);
}
```

Referencia: https://www.educba.com/linq-intersect/

Comment: Siento que mi pregunta iba a encaminada hacia esta parte